# How can admin pay the seller after deduct his commission and automatically every week and if he can also hold and release payment

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-5, paypal-sandbox

I am making a project in of eCommerce the condition is that buyer buy any this the payment goes to admin account after one week admin commission automatically deduct from that payment than automatically transfer to seller account if admin want to hold that payment he can hold and when he click release the payment will release

**This project is making in php or laravel**

This condition is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PayPal Adaptive Payments API for this.

Comment: i wanna ask that the condition that i have told it is possible

Comment: My answer was in response to the condition possible or not.